# When is the product rule applicable? or, What's going on here?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

My course problem booklet (mathematics BSc, second year module in algebra, unpublished) has a question,

> Let $D:=x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Calculate an expression for $D^2$ in terms of $x$ and $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$.

The solution booklet has
\begin{aligned}
D^2f
& = x\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}\right) \\
& = x\left[\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}+x\frac{\text{d}^2f}{\text{d}x^2}\right].
\end{aligned}

I can't immediately understand this in first-principle terms. It looks to me like an application of the product rule, but we haven't derived the product rule in the context of linear operators on vector spaces, so I'm not sure why it should be obvious that it can be applied. Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: Have you tried applying the "simplest" product rule that you know?

Comment: $\Bbb{R}[x]$ means the polynomials with real coefficients, and derivatives of polynomials certainly satisfies the product rule (actually for polynomials, the product rule and the power rule are equivalent, because of linearity of derivatives)

Comment: @peek-a-boo But don't derivatives of polynomials satisfy the product rule for reasons which depend on how linear operators between vector spaces work, i.e. the sort of thing being investigated here?

Comment: @mjc $\frac{d}{dx}$ certainly satisfies the product rule: for any $f(x),g(x)\in \Bbb{R}[x]$, $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)g(x)]=f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}(x)+\frac{df}{dx}(x)g(x)$. This can be proved very easily from the definitions, so I'm not too sure what the issue is (if you want a proof: start with $f(x)=x^m, g(x)=x^n$, and verify it in this case. THen, note that the formula is bilinear in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, hence the general case follows). You're using the product rule nature of $\frac{d}{dx}$ to derive the corresponding expression for $D^2=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I can accept that the product rule holds for any $f(x),g(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, but here it's being applied to an operator, $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}$, which isn't in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: NO. The product rule is not applied to an operator. Can you tell me where? We are taking  an arbitrary $f(x)\in \Bbb{R}[x]$, and trying to calculate $D^2f=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{df}{dx}\right)$. Inside the brackets, $x$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$ are polynomials which are multiplied, and you're applying $\frac{d}{dx}$ to them, so the product rule is used. So I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @peek-a-boo OK I think I've got it. I was slipping on the point that $D^nf \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer, answer your question?

Comment: @Logic Sort of.

Comment: Well then you should accept/upvote it, so that this question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @Logic I can see that closing the question is good, but I'm conflicted on accepting an answer when I found an exchange in the comments more useful. I suppose I could ask peek-a-boo to write up his comments as an answer if you think it's important enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s an application of the product rule, what’s so surprising? $\mathbb{R[x]}$ is just the set of all real polynomials and polynomials satisfy the product rule.
 There’s nothing being used about linear operators, what’s being used is that $d/dx$ satisfies the product rule.
Judging from your comment, your problem seems to be that that the product rule is being applied to $x\times df/dx$ but that’s no problem because both $x$ and $df/dx$ are  differentiable polynomial functions [because $f$ is a polynomial].